# php write and read checkboxes option to a text file

Tags: php, database, forms, text

We are making a small app for my school in php language.
We would need to create two pages:
Control Panel: A small page where you can select options and insert a text into a form and save it to a txt database
Wiev Page: page where you read the options selected and saved in db.
[example app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8PwK.jpg)

Unfortunately, we do not have such advanced PHP knowledge
Can you help us?
thank you all

Comment: Questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a coding writing service, so if you need help with that,  I suggest you contact a web development company, they do stuff like that. Here we help users that has a coding problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use fopen("testfile.txt", "w") u can write text into file

```
$myfile = fopen("dbtextfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "We are selected: option1 , option3";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
```

please check [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)